# In IOS5 How do We Get FirstName, LastName, BirthDay, Username, and PictureProfileURL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I want to enable user to sign in to my app with twitter. Once signed in, I will call my server and store their username, firstname, lastname, gender, birthday, email, etc.

```
+(NSString *) URLforSaveUserDataBirthDay: (NSString *)birthday email:(NSString*)email gender:(NSString*)gender firstname:(NSString*)first_name lastname:(NSString *)last_name URLForPictureProfile:(NSString *) urlforpictureprofile
{
    //NSString * birthday=user[@"birthday"];
    //NSString * email  = user[@"email"];
    //NSString * gender = user[@"gender"];
    //NSString * token = [BGGenerateTK generateTK];
    NSString * URLaddUser = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/business/api/saveuserdata.php?username=%@&first_name=%@&last_name=%@&gender=%@&birthday=%@&email=%@&image=%@%@",urlServer,[self encodedUserID],first_name.RobustURLEncodedString,last_name.RobustURLEncodedString,gender.toGenderCode,birthday.RobustURLEncodedString,email.RobustURLEncodedString,urlforpictureprofile.RobustURLEncodedString,self.andEncodedandDeviceIDLatLongUserIDWithTk];
    return URLaddUser;
}
```

I look at various code and I am really confused.

For IOS, do we have to do low level work like computing signature getting oauth token etc? I want to support IOS5. Some website write I should use twitter framework reference.

However, there is tutorial anywhere explaining how to use twitter framework reference to sign in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Guides these links can be helpful:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5

http://www.peterfriese.de/the-accounts-and-twitter-framework-on-ios-5/